# How to fit a logistic growth model using the Newton–Raphson algorithm?

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

Table 2.3

| Days | Beetles |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 8 | 47 |
| 28 | 192 |
| 41 | 256 |
| 63 | 768 |
| 79 | 896 |
| 97 | 1120 |
| 117 | 896 |
| 135 | 1185 |
| 154 | 1024 |

Table 2.3 provides counts of a ﬂour beetle (Tribolium confusum) population at various points in time [103]. Beetles in all stages of development were counted, and the food supply was carefully controlled.
An elementary model for population growth is the logistic model given by

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=r N (1-\frac{N}{K})$$

where N is population size, t is time, r is a growth rate parameter, and K is a parameter that represents the population carrying capacity of the environment. The solution to this differential equation is given by

$$N_{t}=f(t)=\frac{K N_{0}}{N_{0}+(K-N_{0})\exp(-rt)}$$

(a): Fit the logistic growth model to the ﬂour beetle data using the Newton–Raphson approach to minimize the sum of squared errors between model predictions and observed counts.

(b): In many population modelling applications, an assumption of lognormality is adopted. The simplest assumption would be that the log N t are independent and normally distributed with mean log f(t) and variance $\sigma^{2}$ . Find the MLEs under this assumption, using both the Gauss–Newton and the Newton–Raphson methods. Provide standard errors for your parameter estimates, and an estimate of the correlation between them. Comment.

I was trying to use pracma package in R to solve part B, but it did not work out. I did not see any package in R that can fit a logtistic growth model using Newton–Raphson algorithm. I tried using newtonsys in pracma package, but it did not work.

Comment: What does "did not work out" mean exactly? What did your code look like? What did it fail to do?

Comment: I knew it was not the right function to use, there are some ways to fit this kind of model, one way is to use nls function, another way is to use optim in R, I was not sure for Newton–Raphson algorithm, which package would be more appropriate, I tried pracma but it was not the one.

Comment: This sounds like no package should be used. You have a simple scalar function mapping k to the mean square error. Its first and second derivative are likewise easy to implement, then combine to the Newton loop. End it if the step in the k parameter or the first derivative (relative to its original value or the function value) become small enough.